# Error when typing accented letters in author field

Tags: document-classes, accents, author, autart

The following code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
        \author[MyCity]{Mar\'{c}us}\ead{myemail@gmail.com},
        \address[MyCity]{My University, My address, My City}                                          
        
        \begin{abstract}
            Hello, abstract!
        \end{abstract}
    \end{frontmatter}
    Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

produces several errors related to missing/extra curly braces

```
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.10)
entering extended mode
(d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-10-18> (autart.cls
Document Class: autart 2001/03/28, 2.18pl1: Automatica
(C:\Users\Moon Raven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latexsym.sty) (C:\Users\Moon Raven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ulasy.fd)) (C:\Users\Moon Raven\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def) (main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `MyCity' on page 1 undefined on input line 4.

\protect 
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Too many }'s.
\@ead@au ...norespaces \relax \accent 19 c\egroup 
                                                  \spacefactor \accent@space...
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Extra \endgroup.
\color@endgroup ->\endgraf \endgroup 
                                     
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Too many }'s.
\@footnotetext ...strutbox }\par \color@endgroup }
                                                  
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Too many }'s.
\output@ead@text ... \csname #1@text\endcsname .}}
                                                  \fi 
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Too many }'s.
\output@glob@notes ... \the \t@glob@notes \egroup 
                                                  
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       

d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{frontmatter}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
d:/minimal_working_example/main.tex:10: Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.10    \end{frontmatter}
                       
[1{C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)<C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx9.pfb><C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb><C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb><C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl9.pfb><C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti9.pfb><C:/Users/Moon Raven/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt9.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 99906 bytes).
SyncTeX written on main.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Reference `MyCity' on page 1 undefined on input line 4
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 reference(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'main.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

which seem to be caused by the accented letter inside the author field. The accented letter does not seem to pose a problem in any other part of the document. What's going on?

Comment: Can you include the error message(s) in your question? Also, does `{Mar\'cus}` work?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the error messages. I receive the same errors when I try to remove the curly braces around the letter 'c', as you suggested.

Comment: Where does not get that document class? It is not a known one

Comment: What happens if you write `Mar{\'c}us`?

Comment: @Mico I also get the errors. There are just two additonal  error lines, compared to the version I have posted in the question.

Comment: @daleif It is a class for a journal, downloaded from [here](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/automatica/0005-1098/guide-for-authors)

Comment: The actual download link is http://www.elsevier.com/__data/promis_misc/automatica_latex.zip

Comment: And if you add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: Works for me with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Please, please start showing the courtesy of reporting what exactly you input and what exactly the error messages are you get in return. A statement such as "There are just two additonal error lines, compared to the version I have posted in the question" is so non-specific as to be virtually meaningless.

Comment: @Mico sorry, I just got an additional pair of "Missing } inserted." and "Too many }'s." when I tried the suggestion `Mar{\'c}us`. All the remaining error messages were exactly the same.

@Bernard @daleif It also seems to be working for me with the fontenc package; I was trying the inputenc package, which doesn't seem to be the correct approach. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

The authors of the class use very dangerous `\xdef` and `\edef` commands. They try to add a self-made protection with a macro `\no@harm` that, unfortunately, fails to cover the most common cases.

Fixing with the standard protection mechanisms solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\@xnamedef#1{\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname #1\endcsname}
\def\no@harm{} % now useless
\def\ead@au#1{\protected@edef\@ead@au{#1}}
\patchcmd\runningauthor@fmt{\global\edef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\patchcmd\runningauthor@fmt{\global\edef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\patchcmd\author@fmt{\edef}{\protected@edef}{}{}
\patchcmd\add@xtok{\xdef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\author[MyCity]{Mar\'{c}us}\ead{myemail@gmail.com},
\address[MyCity]{My University, My address, My City}

\begin{abstract}
  Hello, abstract!
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

Hello, world!

\end{document}
```

[image]