# Compilation stops when french accents are present in frontmatter in autart document class

Tags: accents, front-matter, autart

Compilation stops when I have french accents in the frontmatter of autart documentclass.

The following code, with no accents, compiles correctly.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
    \title{ Titi }
    \author[xx]{Malty}\ead{me@myself.com},
    \address[xx]{University}
\end{frontmatter}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

But if you substitute `Malty` by `Malté` or `University` by `Université`, the compilation stops with the following log.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded   format=pdflatex)
\write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-09-28> (./autart.cls
Document Class: autart 2001/03/28, 2.18pl1: Automatica
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./MWE.aux)
```

However if you substitute Malty by Malti\'c the following error appears

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
\write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-09-28> (./autart.cls
Document Class: autart 2001/03/28, 2.18pl1: Automatica
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./MWE.aux)
\protect 
./MWE.tex:8: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.8 \end{frontmatter}
                 
? q
OK, entering \batchmode
```

Any workaround?

Comment: you should add a reference for the class, it is not in texlive.

Comment: Both runs seem to stop after reading in MWE.aux, after changes are made to the main file.  Did you try removing the .aux file before rerunning?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what do you mean by a reference?

Comment: @barbarabeeton yeah I tried removing the .aux file. But it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

The class basically does

```
{\def\protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}\edef\blub{Malté}\blub}
```

and that loops (or errors with accent commands).

You could try this, but then don't use commands in the names, only proper unicode chars.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}
\makeatletter 
\def\no@harm{}
\makeatother
  
\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
    \title{ Titi }
    \author[xx]{Malté}\ead{me@myself.com},
    \address[xx]{Université}
\end{frontmatter}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

A more thorough patch can be found in the egreg's answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621443/2388

Comment: This solution fixes the issue related to French accents. Thanks a lot. BUT it did not fix the issue related to the presence of \'c character (last part of my post), which still generates errors. Any complement?

Comment: yes, as I wrote: don't use accents commands they break in the \edef, use the proper unicode input, `ć`.

Comment: Right. It works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: oh there is a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621443/2388

Comment: Just defining `\no@harm` to a no-op isn't really enough.

Comment: @egreg for accent commands certainly not, but with utf8 chars it could work now that they are protected.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The class authors seem not to be aware of the existence of `\protected@edef` and `\protected@xdef`. Leaving their code as is can lead to several problems, not only with accents.

Comment: @egreg I quite agree that the code it bad and your patches are more complete, that's why I linked to them as duplicate. I will add it also to the answer.